# Solving this simple linear system [Linear Algebra].

Tags: linear-algebra

The solution given shows $a = 2r + 6s$, $b = -3r - 7s$.

When I attempted to solve it myself, I put the two equations into a coefficient matrix, and row reduced, which gave me $a = r + 3s$, $b = -2r - 4s$.

How was the conclusion given in the solution reached?

[image: polynomial basis]

Comment: What is the linear system?

Comment: It looks like you didn't finish the row reduction, which (if I'm following your thoughts) ought to eliminate the $r$ term in the second equation.

Answer (score 0):

Are you sure that you are doing your row reduction correctly?
Setting up the matrix,
$$M = \left( \begin{smallmatrix} 1&1&1&1&0 \\ 1&2&4&8&0 \end{smallmatrix} \right)$$
Subtracting the first row from the second row:
$$M = \left( \begin{smallmatrix} 1&1&1&1&0 \\ 0&1&3&7&0 \end{smallmatrix} \right)$$
Now subtracting the second row from the first row:
$$M = \left( \begin{smallmatrix} 1&0&-2&-6&0 \\ 0&1&3&7&0 \end{smallmatrix} \right)$$
From here it is easy to see how they got $a=2r+6s, b=-3r-7s, c=r, d=s$.
I would check your row reduction again.